# Groovy vs Jenkins - regex replaceFirst/replaceAll function with closure works differently in Jenkins shared library

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy, closures, shared-libraries

I try to create a Jenkins shared library. For this I created unit testable Groovy classes, like versioning. I have a regex pattern and I want to replace the version string with the matching parameters in a groovy closure. In Junit tests everything works fine, but from Jenkins, I only got nulls in all parameters, if I use multiparameter closure.

My versioning function:

```
static String getNewVersion(String oldVersion, VersioningType type) {
        Pattern pattern = ~/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(-.*)?$/
        switch (type) {
            case VersioningType.INC_PATCH:
              //Closure incPatchNotworkingFromJenkins = { _, major, minor, patch, postfix -> "${major}.${minor}.{(patch as int) + 1}{postfix :? ""}"}  
                Closure incPatch = { matchgroups -> "${matchgroups[1]}.${matchgroups[2]}.${(matchgroups[3] as int) + 1 }${matchgroups[4] ?: ""}" }
                return oldVersion.replaceAll(pattern, incPatch)
    }
}
```

This works, but with the Closure in the comment Jenkins only got null-s in all parameters, only the _ parameter gets the value. If I println the parameters, I got [0.1.1, null, null, null, null], null, null, null, null.

Anybody can help me with this? Why Jenkins does not understand multiparameter closures?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make your function @NonCPS

```
@NonCPS
static String getNewVersion(String oldVersion, VersioningType type) {
        Pattern pattern = ~/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(-.*)?$/
        switch (type) {
            case VersioningType.INC_PATCH:
                Closure incPatchNotworkingFromJenkins = { _, major, minor, patch, postfix -> "${major}.${minor}.{(patch as int) + 1}{postfix :? ""}"}  
                // Closure incPatch = { matchgroups -> "${matchgroups[1]}.${matchgroups[2]}.${(matchgroups[3] as int) + 1 }${matchgroups[4] ?: ""}" }
                return oldVersion.replaceAll(pattern, incPatch)
    }
}
```

Comment: with this approach I got 
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Versioner$_getNewVersion_closure1.0.1.{(patch as int) + 1}{postfix :? () is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [}]
Versioner is the groovy class containing this method.